# What does it mean to say that "formula is exact for all polynomials of degree less $n$"?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, numerical-methods, terminology

What does it mean that "formula that is exact for all polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2?'

Comment: they are $a+bx+cx^2$ in one indeterminate $x$

Comment: what are those coeffiicients?

Comment: ...just numbers, or elements in a ring

Answer (score 2):

In numerical analysis one uses the following terms

**Degree of exactness** - the largest value of $n$ so that all polynomials of degree $n$ ($x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\dots a_0$) and below are  for which the numerical algorithm results in an exact value, i.e. the error term vanishes for such polynomials.

**Order of accuracy** the value of $n$ so that the error is $ O(h^n)$, where $ h$ measures the subinterval size.

For example numerical scheme for approximating first derivative is given by
$$Df=\frac{u_{i+1}-u_i}h$$
where $u_{i}=u(x_i)$ and $x_i=x_0+ih$.

Let evaluate this scheme at polynomial basis $1,x,x^2,...$

1. $u(x)=1$ :$$D1=\frac{1-1}h=0=u'$$
2. $u(x)=x$ :$$\frac{(x+(i+1)h)-(x+ih)}h=1=u'$$
3. $u(x)=x^2$ :$$\frac{(x+(i+1)h)^2-(x+ih)^2}h=2  x +h(1+ 2  i) =u'+O(h)$$

So the scheme is exact for polynomials of degree $1$ or below, i.e. Degree of exactness**  is $1$. It's order of accuracy in this case is also $1$. The order of accuracy can also be found by substituting Taylor's formula into scheme.